# Shimano Steps 6100 loses power assist climbing hills

Tags: shimano, electric-bike, steps

Having problems with bike losing power going up hill - 4 of last 5 rides.  About 400 miles on bike (BMC Alpenchallenge AMP Sport).  Have several 40+ mile rides with 4,000' of elev, so it works.  Now I'm not even getting 15 miles and have to turn around.  Randomly loses power while going up hill, but so far it comes back on after turning around and going back down.

No error codes yet.

Did have 1 ride last year where it stopped completely & took 45 minutes to come back on.  Found 4 W013 codes for that.

Comment: No error codes and everything seeming normal when it works strongly implies a connectivity problem somewhere. Be sure to check the bolts that hold down the battery mounting parts.

Comment: For others' reference, here's Shimano's list of common error codes. W013 means that the torque sensor wasn't initialized successfully. https://www.shimano-steps.com/e-bikes/north-america/en/faq/troubleshooting---errors-

Answer (score 1):

The worn battery may refuse any power when too much asked and not sufficiently charged. Simply ride few minutes with no assist. It should recover. Powering the bicyce off and on may help to recover faster.

You can avoid this problem by using a more charged battery, selecting low level of assist and switching into lower gear.

In my case the problem invariably occurs exclusively under combination of the half charged only battery, high load (steep uphill, extra luggage) and high assist. The battery indicator suddenly drops to 0, no power available, then slowly recovers. Motor overheating would not depend on the battery charge. And it was not in the beginning, only now when the bike gets old. It is Diavelo with Bafang engine, not Shimano, but probably the same.

At some point it comes time for a new battery.